# C# - Intercambiar el primer y ultimo nodo de una lista enlazada simple

Tags: c#, lista

Construir una lista enlazada simple, agregar nodos al principio y al final de la lista, intercambiar el primero y ultimo nodo de la lista.

Clase Nodo

```
public class Nodo
    {
        public Nodo(int pID, Nodo pNodo) { Identificador = pID; Siguiente = pNodo; }
        public int Identificador { get; set; }
        public Nodo Siguiente { get; set; }
    }
```

Clase Lista

```
     public void Swap()
        {
            try
            {
                Nodo primero = centinelaPrimero.Siguiente;
                Nodo ultimo = centinelaUltimo.Siguiente;

                Nodo anteUltimo = centinelaPrimero.Siguiente;
                while (anteUltimo.Siguiente.Siguiente != null)
                {
                    anteUltimo = anteUltimo.Siguiente;
                }
                Interaction.MsgBox(anteUltimo.Identificador.ToString()); // esto lo use para que me diga si ese nodo que encontró era el anteultimo o no.

                ultimo.Siguiente = primero.Siguiente;
                primero.Siguiente = null;
                centinelaPrimero.Siguiente = ultimo;
                centinelaUltimo.Siguiente = primero;
                anteUltimo.Siguiente = primero;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }
        }
```

Comment: No se puede hacer en tiempo constante a menos que guardes una referencia al penúltimo nodo también. De lo contrario tendrías que recorrer la lista completa.

Comment: No es necesario que aclares que esta finalizado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando vos tenes una lista, un nodo apunta al siguiente. y el ultimo, no apunta a ningun lado...

Lo que tiene que hacer tu algoritmo es:

Mover el siguiente del ultimo nodo (sea cual sea) al siguiente del primer nodo.
Mover el siguiente del primer nodo, a null (ya que pasa a ser el ultimo de la lista).
Intercambiar los punteros primero y ultimo de tu clase lista.

Ahora el problema que tenemos es con el anteultimo nodo. Si no guardas un puntero al anteultimo, lo que tenes que hacer es recorrer la lista, nodo por nodo, buscando aquel que apunte al que ahora es el primero. Cuando lo encuentres, reemplazas la referencia por la del ultimo nodo y listo.

Comment: YA LO PUDE HACER! me ayudaste un monton muchas gracias!